# Accessing data in a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid, entity-framework-4.3

I have the following entity framework code snippet which has a "Groups" table and a child "ApplicationsGroupsLK" table that contains an ApplicationID field that I need.

```
IEnumerable<Groups> Groups = DbContext.Groups.Include("ApplicationsGroupsLK").Where(p => p.GroupNumber > 0);
```

The child data comes back obviously in a collection.

I basically need to display the parent data along with the child ApplicationID field (many Applications to 1 Group).

### In my MVC View, what should my ViewModel look like that would contain the parent and child data coming back that I need in order that I can properly bind it to a grid?

Second post:

Further, the following model was generated from Entity Framework:

```
public partial class Project
    {
        public Project()
        {
            this.TimeTrackings = new HashSet<TimeTracking>();
        }

     [DataMember]
        public short ProjectID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public short CustomerID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public short CategoryID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public short PriorityID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public short StatusID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public Nullable<decimal> Quote { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<TimeTracking> TimeTrackings { get; set; }
    }
```

You can see that TimeTrackings is the child table of Project. You can also see that CategoryID, CustomerID, PriorityID, and StatusID are foreign keys that the parent table has. In this case, I'm only interested in the CategoryID FK.

### I haven't done this yet (not at my machine at home), but when I get the data into this model, **what would actually be contained in the public virtual Category Category field**? Since it's not a collection, what data is returned in this field after the query executes.

Third post:
Telerik asp.net for mvc syntax for DB call:

```
IEnumerable<Groups> GroupList = db.GetGroups();

            return View(new GridModel<Groups>
            {
                Data = GroupList
            });
```

---

Fourth post:
Trey, below is the code I modified for my purposes and was hoping you can check it over before I implement it. I think I undersand it and seems great...

```
public partial class Project
    {
        public Project()
        {
            this.TimeTrackings = new HashSet<TimeTracking>();
        }

     [DataMember]
        public short ProjectID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public short CustomerID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public short CategoryID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public short PriorityID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public short StatusID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public Nullable<decimal> Quote { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public short ApplicationID { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<TimeTracking> TimeTrackings { get; set; }


     public ProjectModel(Project project)
     {
        ProjectID = project.ProjectID;
        CustomerID = project.CustomerID;
        Name = project.Name;
        Description = project.Description;
    CategoryID = project.CategoryID;
        PriorityID = project.PriorityID;
        StatusID = project.StatusID;
        Quote = project.Quote;
        Notes = project.Notes;
        CreatedDate = project.CreatedDate;
        UpdatedDate = project.UpdatedDate;
        ApplicationID = project.ApplicationsGroupsLK.ApplicationID;
        ApplicationName = project.ApplicationsGroupsLK.ApplicationName;
     }


     // Neat Linq trick to convert database query results directly to Model
     public static IList<ProjectModel> FlattenToThis(IList<Project> projects)
     {
        return projects.Select(project => new ProjectModel(project)).ToList();
     }

    }
```

---

Fifth post:

```
using (wmswebEntities DbContext = new wmswebEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    IEnumerable<Projects> projects = DbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.GroupNumber > 0);

                    IList<ProjectModel> results = Project.FlattenToThis(projects);

                    return results
```

### }

Sixth post
namespace CMSEFModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public partial class GroupModel
{
    public GroupModel()
    {
        this.ApplicationsGroupsLKs = new HashSet<ApplicationsGroupsLK>();
        this.GroupApplicationConfigurationsLKs = new HashSet<GroupApplicationConfigurationsLK>();
        this.UsersGroupsLKs = new HashSet<UsersGroupsLK>();
    }

    public int GroupNumber { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int GroupRank { get; set; }
    public bool ActiveFlag { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    // Application - Lazy Loading population
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    // UsersGroupsLK - Lazy Loading population
    public int UserNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationsGroupsLK> ApplicationsGroupsLKs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupApplicationConfigurationsLK> GroupApplicationConfigurationsLKs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UsersGroupsLK> UsersGroupsLKs { get; set; }

    public GroupModel()
    {}
    public GroupModel(GroupModel group)
     {
        GroupNumber = group.GroupNumber;
        GroupName = group.GroupName;
        ActiveFlag = group.ActiveFlag;
        DateAdded = group.DateAdded;
        AddedBy = group.AddedBy;
        LastUpdated = group.LastUpdated;
        LastUpdatedBy = group.LastUpdatedBy;
        UserNumber = group.UsersGroupsLKs.
     }


 // Neat Linq trick to convert database query results directly to Model
 public static IList<GroupModel> FlattenToThis(IList<GroupModel> groups)
 {
    return groups.Select(group => new GroupModel(group)).ToList();
 }
}
```

### }

Seventh Post - this is the model I am having trouble with about the errors I previously posted. Trey, if you could help, I WOULD REALLY APPRECIATE IT.... I'm "dead in the water" unless I can get this part working.

```
namespace CMSEFModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Group
    {
        public Group()
        {
            this.ApplicationsGroupsLKs = new HashSet<ApplicationsGroupsLK>();
            this.GroupApplicationConfigurationsLKs = new HashSet<GroupApplicationConfigurationsLK>();
            this.UsersGroupsLKs = new HashSet<UsersGroupsLK>();
        }

        public int GroupNumber { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public int GroupRank { get; set; }
        public bool ActiveFlag { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public string AddedBy { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
        // Application - Lazy Loading population
        public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
        // UsersGroupsLK - Lazy Loading population
        public int UserNumber { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationsGroupsLK> ApplicationsGroupsLKs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GroupApplicationConfigurationsLK> GroupApplicationConfigurationsLKs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UsersGroupsLK> UsersGroupsLKs { get; set; }

        public GroupModel(Group group)
         {
            GroupNumber = group.GroupNumber;
            GroupName = group.GroupName;
            ActiveFlag = group.ActiveFlag;
            DateAdded = group.DateAdded;
            AddedBy = group.AddedBy;
            LastUpdated = group.LastUpdated;
            LastUpdatedBy = group.LastUpdatedBy;
            UserNumber = group.UsersGroupsLKs.
         }

     // Neat Linq trick to convert database query results directly to Model
     public static IList<GroupModel> FlattenToThis(IList<Group> groups)
     {
        return groups.Select(group => new GroupModel(group)).ToList();
     }
    }
```

### }

Eight post:

```
using (wmswebEntities DbContext = new wmswebEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    List<Groups> myGroups = new List<Groups>();

                     var myGroups = from p in DbContext.Groups
                                where p.ActiveFlag = true
                                select new
                                {
                                    p.Groups.ApplicationName,
                                    p.Groups.GroupName,
                                    p.Groups.GroupRank,
                                    p.Groups.ActiveFlag,
                                    p.Groups.DateAdded,
                                    p.Groups.AddedBy,
                                    p.Groups.LastUpdated,
                                    p.Groups.LastUpdatedBy,
                                    p.Groups.ApplicationsGroupsLK.ApplicationID,
                                    p.Groups.UsersGroupsLK.UserNumber
                                };

                    return myGroups;
                }
```

Comment: If I'm not thinking this through correctly, then I would very much appreciate a chat with you so I can better understand your solution...

Comment: so you have a grid of projects with drop-downs for Categories?

Answer (score 1):

This will take a slight tweak in thinking.  The Grid will only accept a flat model.  This type of question is asked often, here is a starter answer: [Kendo UI Grid - How to Bind to Child Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756973/kendo-ui-grid-how-to-bind-to-child-properties/14774189#14774189)

If that does not help, post more of your code here and I can work through it with you.

Comment: Trey, thanks a lot for answering... Yea, this is the one thing that's holding me back. I'm going to edit my post based on a generated model from EF and ask you a couple of questions or I'd really like ssome real time interaction on this post with you if you can....

Comment: btw, I'm using the Telerik asp.net ajax for mvc, not the kendoui toolset.

Comment: Trey, I tried to follow your solution in my sixzth post above, but tow things are not happening. I'm not getting any intellisense via LazyLoading (which is turned on) in my "public GroupModel(GroupModel group)" method and in the FlattenToThis method, I'm getting the error: "Does not contain a definition for Select..." I would appreciate it VERY MUCH if we could just chat for a couple of mins to rectify this. If it's something simple you see I'm doing wrong in the code, please feel free to respond just to that. Looking forward to your reply...

Comment: Trey, please look at my seventh post. I can't get the intellisense to work for the child tables with the lazy loading. I am also getting the msg: "GroupModel is a method, but used like a type" which is understandable the way it's set up, it resembles a method. PLEASE HELP.....

Comment: Looks like you might be diging yourself into a deeper hole.  I assume you can see my email address in my profile.  I can spend 20-30 minutes on this if you would like this afternoon.  Email me at that address and setup a http://join.me session to share your screen.

Comment: Trey, I sent an ivite to your LinkedIn account. I didn't see any other email address. All I want to do in the code you saw is basically include the ApplicationID & UserNumber in the model for retrieval. In additon, to ensure that the call to the "Flatten" method looks correct. I'll send the join.me session now.

Comment: Trey, I downloaded the software for the join.me session. What do I need to type into the "Join someone's screen" to enter the session with you?

Comment: I think I can just perform code in my edit for my eight post. Take a look and let me know if this is OK. This way, it's very simple...