# Is that possible to instantiate an object when columns are created on a kendo.grid?

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo.grid that has the following defenition of the column:

```
co.Bound(c => c.ReportProperty.PropertyName)
```

There is a Model that has an object defined inside:

`public ReportPropertyEntity ReportProperty { get; set; }`

That object has property `PropertyName`.

I want its value to be displayed on the grid.

When I'm doing that, I'm getting a `javascript` error saying:

> Unable to get property 'PropertyName' of undefined or null reference

I believe that `ReportProperty` object needs to be instantiated before using its property.

I have a kendo.grid that has the following defenition of the column:

```
co.Bound(c => c.ReportProperty.PropertyName)
```

There is a Model that has an object defined inside:

`public ReportPropertyEntity ReportProperty { get; set; }`

That object has property `PropertyName`.

I want its value to be displayed on the grid.

When I'm doing that, I'm getting a `javascript` error saying:

> Unable to get property 'PropertyName' of undefined or null reference

I believe that `ReportProperty` object needs to be instantiated before using its property.

These classes' properties gets mapped from database query and is defined in Entity Project:

```
public class TicketReportPropertyEntity
{
    ReportPropertyEntity ReportProperty { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class ReportPropertyEntity
{
    public int ReportPropertyID { get; set;}
    public string ReportGroup { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public int ReportID { get; set; }
}
```

As you see from that code, `ReportPropertyEntity` class is a part of `TicketReportPropertyEntity`.

This is the query that returns result's XML from which those classes are serialized with the following logic:

```
    var xml = new TicketReportProperty().RunProcedureXmlString("SPU_Get_TicketReportProperty", parameters);

    List<TicketReportPropertyEntity> res = SerializeObject<List<TicketReportPropertyEntity>>.FromXml(xml);

    return res;
```

This is the query that generates XML file from the tables:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT
    (
        SELECT trp.ID, TicketID, ReportID AS "ReportProperty/ReportID", ReportPropertyID AS "ReportProperty/ReportPropertyID",
                        PropertyName AS "ReportProperty/PropertyName", PropertyName, Section AS "ReportProperty/ReportGroup",  Amount
            FROM TicketReportProperty trp  
            INNER JOIN ReportProperty rp ON rp.ID = trp.ReportPropertyID
            WHERE TicketID = 6893
            FOR XML PATH('TicketReportPropertyEntity'), TYPE
    )
) FOR XML PATH('ArrayOfTicketReportPropertyEntity'), TYPE
```

The serialized class is returned to model and its field are bound to the model's fields:

This is the model:

```
    public class TicketReportPropertyModel
    {

        public List<TicketReportPropertyEntity> TicketReportPropertyList { get; set; }

        ReportPropertyEntity ReportProperty { get; set; }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int TicketID { get; set; }
        public int ReportID { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }


        public TicketReportPropertyModel GetTicketReportPropertyData(int ticketId)
        {
            var client = new IeBalanceServiceClient();   
            var report = client.GetTicketReportPropertyData(ticketId).ToList();
            client.Close();

            TicketReportPropertyModel model = MapFromBusinessObject(report);

            return model;
        }

        public TicketReportPropertyModel MapFromBusinessObject(List<TicketReportPropertyEntity> res)
        {
            TicketReportPropertyModel m = new TicketReportPropertyModel();
            m.TicketReportPropertyList = res ?? new 
            List<TicketReportPropertyEntity>();

            return m;
        }

        public List<ReportPropertyEntity> GetReportPropertyData(int reportId)
        {
            List<ReportPropertyEntity> reportProp = TicketReportPropertyRepository.GetReportPropertyEntityRepository(reportId);
            return reportProp;
        }
    }
```

And as I mentioned, in my Grid I have a field contains a `Kendo().ComboBox()` generated from a template:

```
  columns.Bound(c => c.ReportProperty.PropertyName).Title("Property Name").EditorTemplateName("_PropertyNameEditor").Width(900);
```

`ReportProperty` entity is a part of `TicketReportPropertyEntity`.

And this is a `Grid` itself bound to `TicketReportPropertyEntity`:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TicketReportPropertyEntity>()
        .Name("TicketReportPropertyGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(c => c.ReportProperty.PropertyName).Title("Property Name").EditorTemplateName("_PropertyNameEditor").Width(900);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Amount).Title("Amount").Format("{0:C}").Width(90);
            columns.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Destroy();
            }).Width(250);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Create();
            toolbar.Save();
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).ConfirmDelete("Are you sure").DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Delete"))
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("Databound").SaveChanges("SaveGrid").Edit("Edit"))
        .DataSource(datasource => datasource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
        //.PageSize(20)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(c => c.ID);
            model.Field(c => c.PropertyName);
            model.Field(c => c.Amount);
        })
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "TicketReportProperty", Model))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateTicketReportProperty", "TicketReportProperty")))
 )
```

This is how I define `Kendo().ComboBox()` inside of the editor template:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                      .Name("ReportProperty")
                      .DataTextField("PropertyName")
                      .DataValueField("ReportPropertyID")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "ReportPropertyCB" })
                      .Template("<span class=\"k-state-default\"><h3>#: PropertyName #</h3><p>#: ReportGroup #</p></span>")
)
```

This is the line where I'm getting the error message:

> Unable to get property 'PropertyName' of undefined or null reference

```
c.ReportProperty.PropertyName).Title("Property Name").EditorTemplateName("_PropertyNameEditor").Width(900);
```

How can I access the fields of the combobox?

Comment: In your `Read()`, `context.Parent.Include(p => p.ReportProperty)` - assuming the it is EntityFramework. I prefer to flatten those out into a ViewModel.

Comment: How exactly to write the syntax?

Comment: Fields gets bound to data by serialization from XML file created during CRUD operations. It is not entities.

Comment: Show your datasource and the code where entities are fetched and mapped to the grid model.

Comment: I updated the code with more explanation. Hope it will be more clear and I answered your question

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756973/kendo-ui-grid-how-to-bind-to-child-properties) seems to indicate you need to flatten your model which is what I do with automapper.